# How to break down smalldatetime into year, month, day indexes?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008.

I have some dates in my database that I "think" I want to break down into smaller parts.  The dates are birthdays and death days. I want to be able to output them like by querying people who were born in October or on May 12th or in 1945.

I was told that a typical way of doing this is to take a date and break it into smaller pieces and put each piece of the date into its own column, like this:

```
2001-03-12 00:00:00 // EventDate column
```

Add these columns:

```
2001 // EventYear column
03 // EventMonth column
12 // EventDay column
```

First, is this a good way of doing this?  If so, second, can I somehow have SQL Server automatically break the date part and put it into its own columns?

I'd appreciate ideas and solutions.

Comment: How many rows of data do you have in that table?

Comment: There will be 10,000 max rows spread over four to six tables.  I really want to learn the "right" way to do this though. I am not looking to just get it done any old which way. I can already do it four or five "wrong" ways. I want to know how an expert would do it.

Comment: What do you mean spread over 4-6 tables?

Comment: I'll have four or five tables with dates. Each table might have 2,000 rows.

Comment: I see no reason to instruct Erik to split every datetime column for the purpose of querying 2000 records.

Comment: I agree, in this case it is likely a premature optimization. But, at least separate out the code involved so that if at some point this optimization is necessary, you won't have to change N places in your code to find all that has a birthday on a given day, only 1 place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend that you leave it as a date column and then use [DatePart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) in queries to filter results.

```
Select * from TABLEX
where DatePart(YEAR,EventDate) = 1945
```

Comment: How will that perform when the query is for May 12th?

Comment: This is the correct way to deal with manipulation of datetime columns. It makes little sense to duplicate the date into multiple columns unless you are talking about a database that has millions of records and performance is extremely important. This functionality has a low cost and should perform fine.

Comment: I certainly won't have millions of dates, probably only a few thousand. I want to do it as though there were a million dates though. I'd much rather write a query like select * from DateTable where Year = 1945 than do the date part thing in every query.

Comment: The major benefit to using datepart is that you don't need to think about creating a new column every time that you want to slice the data differently. For example...if you decided that you wanted to know all events that happened on a Saturday, you wouldn't need to create another column for day of the week, you would just use datepart weekday.

Comment: The major downside is that every query would be a tablescan, *possibly* with the exception of one that includes year, month, day, etc. in that order (I don't know if DatePart is sargable, but partial queries are definitely not.)

Comment: Rather than adding columns, duplicating data and adding unnecessary complexity I would definitely recommend using Joe's approach. However, the others do have a point about the efficiency with repeated queries and large data sets. You probably want to look at creating views or temporary tables that have already done the work.

Comment: I think your answer will work for me now and in the distant future on this project.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't sound like the business requirement is very solidified.  For what reason would you need to break out the different parts of the date?  If you don't need to, then I wouldn't.

But, if you do find the necessity to do this then I'd utilize computed columns that are persisted.  There wil lbe some overhead on an insert, but because there won't be any updates on existing data (your birthdate and death date won't change) then you won't see any performance overhead on a SELECT.

Something like this:

```
create table DateTest
(
    SomeDate datetime not null,
    SomeYear as datepart(yy, somedate) persisted,
    SomeMonth as datepart(mm, somedate) persisted,
    SomeDay as datepart(dd, somedate) persisted
)
```

Comment: +1 for computed columns but dont forget to add an index as well or you will have a table scan using the columns anyway. And the computed column on year is not really necessary. You can use the date column directly for that.

Comment: Interesting solution. It's above my experience level, but I am going to research it and keep it in mind.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I do.

I have a table "lib.Dates". It has a DATE as primary key.

It has additional columns with additional information to this date. This is for example day of month, day to end of month, week of year etc.

Joining this date table with dates allows me to:
* Get a list of all dates (for example grouping sales per person by date would have no entry for zero sales, this way it can have)
* Do funny things like all dates in week 23 of a year, which is normally harder to get.

This is part of a number of such tables that I have stored procedures maintain daily (-3 years, +5 years).

Comment: You mean a `Calendar` table that every other table with a `date` field can reference it as `FOREIGN KEY`? So, no other table will need persisted, indexed views? If yes, +1 from me.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It also belongs to a library project I maintain - I sometimes add new tables here. Especially the join thing is very nice at times (as it callows me to ahve a list of ALL dates, not only the dates that have data).

Comment: Yes, similar questions appear from time to time in SO, "find all dates that no orders were taken".

Comment: TomTom, this is an interesting solution, but it's too much for me. I appreciate your introducing me to the idea though.